# How to add HTML code into a link_to tag in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my link_to tag :

```
<%= link_to "Signout", dasharea_signout_path, method: "delete", id: "adminsignout"  %>
```

I need to add

```
<i class="fa fa-tasks">
```

into the 'a' tag created by the above code. How can I do this?

Comment: By "add the tag into" do you mean like this: `<a><i></i></a>`, since the `<i>` tag needs to be closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a block to the `link_to` helper

```
<%= link_to dasharea_signout_path, method: "delete", id: "adminsignout" do %>
  <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
  <span>Signup</span>
<% end %>
```

The block content will be wrapped in the link tag.

Comment: I don't know why but when I use this code it adds the `<i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>` in every like every link in the page. Its messing up

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

```
<%= link_to "Signout <i class='fa fa-tasks'></i>", dasharea_signout_path, method: "delete", id: "adminsignout"  %>
```

OR
in HAML

```
%a#adminsignout{other properties}
  Signout
  %i.fa.fa-tasks
```